# PySpark SparkSession Builder with Kubernetes Master

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, kubernetes, jupyter

I recently saw a [pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21092) that was merged to the Apache/Spark repository that apparently adds initial Python bindings for PySpark on K8s. I posted a comment to the PR asking a question about how to use spark-on-k8s in a Python Jupyter notebook, and was told to ask my question here.

My question is:

Is there a way to create SparkContexts using PySpark's `SparkSession.Builder` with master set to `k8s://<...>:<...>`, and have the resulting jobs run on `spark-on-k8s`, instead of on `local`?

E.g.:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('k8s://https://kubernetes:443').getOrCreate()
```

I have an interactive Jupyter notebook running inside a Kubernetes pod, and I'm trying to use PySpark to create a `SparkContext` that runs on spark-on-k8s instead of resorting to using `local[*]` as `master`.

Till now, I've been getting an error saying that:

> Error: Python applications are currently not supported for Kubernetes.

whenever I set `master` to `k8s://<...>`.

It seems like PySpark always runs in `client` mode, which doesn't seem to be supported for `spark-on-k8s` at the moment -- perhaps there's some workaround that I'm not aware of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get this worked out?

Comment: Unfortunately not -- I'm still looking for a way to run jobs on Spark-on-K8s in some sort of interactive shell. I came close with [Apache Toree](https://toree.apache.org/), but that didn't end up working out either.

Comment: I've experienced the same as @LucasHu. Tried all different kinds of options w/ Apache Toree, but can't get passed it trying to load a service account token locally.

Answer (score 5):

pyspark client mode works on Spark's latest version 2.4.0

This is how I did it (in Jupyter lab):

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']="/usr/bin/python3.6"
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON']="/usr/bin/python3.6"

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sparkConf = SparkConf()
sparkConf.setMaster("k8s://https://localhost:6443")
sparkConf.setAppName("KUBERNETES-IS-AWESOME")
sparkConf.set("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "robot108/spark-py:latest")
sparkConf.set("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "playground")

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Note: I am running kubernetes locally on Mac with Docker Desktop.