# Create SparkSession with master set to k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Working on a POC for Spark over K8s (Spark ver 2.4.4).

I was able to invoke a spark job using spark-submit:

```
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://localhost:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=liranbo/k8s-test4:latest --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --name spark-pi local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar 40
```

Trying to do the same programmatically using SparkSession builder.

```
SparkSession.builder().appName(appName).master("k8s://https://localhost:8443")
```

And I'm getting the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'k8s://https://localhost:8443'
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2784)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:493)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
at SparkPi.startBySparkSessionBuilder(SparkPi.java:46)
at Runner.main(Runner.java:9)
```

Is it possible to set the master url to K8s when using SparkSession? if not why is supported by spark-submit?

BTW: I was able to start the app programmatically using [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html), but this is not the solution I'm after.

I saw a (possibly) working example in [sparkPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862204/pyspark-sparksession-builder-with-kubernetes-master).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just in case someone runs into the same issue - the issue is related to a missing jar. add the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-kubernetes_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That the docs missed such a crucial piece of information is so frustrating